# Progressively operate on total

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This query sums some values and then calculates a discount and then on the resulting total calculates tax. Is there a better way of doing this that doesn't result in projection after projection...?

```
SELECT
    Total,
    Discount,
    TotalDiscounted,
    TotalDiscounted * 0.2 AS VAT
FROM
    (SELECT
        Total,
        Discount,
        Total - Discount AS TotalDiscounted
    FROM
        (SELECT
            Total,
            Total * 0.1 AS Discount
        FROM
            (SELECT
                SUM(Value) AS Total
            FROM
                (SELECT 1 AS Value UNION
                SELECT 2) a ) b ) c ) d
```

Result...

> 3,    0.3,    2.7,    0.54

Comment: What do you mean by "projection after projection"?   What measurable quality would make another solution "better"?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful

Comment: @TabAlleman A less repetitive and verbose query. Or one that's data driven, where the data is a set of operations.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Sample data is in the query. For desired results, please see above comment.

Comment: @IanWarburton  Yup, I see that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer `CROSS APPLY` to create row-wise computed values you can use like you'd use a variable. This example is to *fat*, but I wanted to show the *beauty of apply*:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(GroupingID INT, [Value] DECIMAL(10,4));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,1),(1,2)          --Group 1 has 1 and 2
                      ,(2,10),(2,15),(2,20);--Group 2 has 10, 15 and 20

WITH cte AS
(                     
    SELECT GroupingID
          ,SUM(t.[Value]) AS SumValue
    FROM @tbl t 
    GROUP BY t.GroupingID
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SumValue * 0.1) A(Discount)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT SumValue-Discount) B(TotalDiscounted)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TotalDiscounted * 0.2) C(VAT);
```

This is fully setbased. The cte does a sum per group and its result set is used in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    SUM(Value) AS Total,
    SUM(Value) * 0.1 AS Discount,
    SUM(Value) - SUM(Value) * 0.1 AS TotalDiscounted,
    (SUM(Value) - SUM(Value) * 0.1) * 0.2 AS VAT
FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS Value UNION
    SELECT 2) a
```

Comment: Please take a look : [SUM same column twice performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164667/sum-same-column-twice-performance)

Comment: That's good to know. My concern is more with maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CROSS APPLY to be able to use/reuse your derived fields

```
WITH TotalBase
AS
(   
    SELECT  SUM(SQ1.Value) AS Total
    FROM    (
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT 2
            ) AS SQ1(Value)
)
SELECT  A.Total,
        CA1.Discount,
        CA2.TotalDiscounted,
        CA3.VAT
FROM    TotalBase AS A
CROSS
APPLY   (SELECT A.Total * 0.1) AS CA1(Discount)
CROSS
APPLY   (SELECT A.Total - CA1.Discount) AS CA2(TotalDiscounted)
CROSS
APPLY   (SELECT CA2.TotalDiscounted * 0.2) AS CA3(VAT);
```